# Histogram Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, histogram

So I have a little problem. I have a data set in scipy that is already in the histogram format, so I have the center of the bins and the number of events per bin. How can I now plot is as a histogram. I tried just doing

```
bins, n=hist()
```

but it didn't like that. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=50)
width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2
plt.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The object-oriented interface is also straightforward:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
fig.savefig("1.png")
```

---

If you are using custom (non-constant) bins, you can pass compute the widths using `np.diff`, pass the widths to `ax.bar` and use `ax.set_xticks` to label the bin edges:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
bins = [0, 40, 60, 75, 90, 110, 125, 140, 160, 200]
hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
width = np.diff(bins)
center = (bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
ax.bar(center, hist, align='center', width=width)
ax.set_xticks(bins)
fig.savefig("/tmp/out.png")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to pass the bin edges to the x-axis of the bar graph?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: `plt.bar`'s `width` parameter can accept an array-like object (instead of a scalar). So you could use `width = np.diff(bins)` instead of `width = 0.7 * (bins[1] - bins[0])`.

Comment: But the `width` setting by itself only sets the width of the bar right? I'm talking about the x-axis labels (that is I want to see the actual bin edges being labels on the x-axis). It should be similar to how `plt.hist` works.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: You could use `ax.set_xticks` to set the xlabels. I've added an example above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 27):

If you don't want bars you can plot it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

bins, edges = np.histogram(x, 50, normed=1)
left,right = edges[:-1],edges[1:]
X = np.array([left,right]).T.flatten()
Y = np.array([bins,bins]).T.flatten()

plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram]

Comment: You can also use `ax.step`.

Answer (score 15):

I know this does not answer your question, but I always end up on this page, when I search for the matplotlib solution to histograms, because the simple `histogram_demo` was removed from the matplotlib example gallery page.

Here is a solution, which doesn't require `numpy` to be imported. I only import numpy to generate the data `x` to be plotted. It relies on the function [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) instead of the function [`bar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) as in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5328669/778533) by @unutbu.

```
import numpy as np
mu, sigma = 100, 15
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(x, bins=50)
plt.savefig('hist.png')
```

[image]

Also check out the [matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) and the [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html).

Comment: "Here is a solution, which doesn't require numpy" -- first line of code imports numpy :)

Comment: @Martin R. That's only to generate the data to be plotted. See lines 4-6. No use of numpy.

Answer (score 11):

I just realized that the [`hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) documentation is explicit about what to do when you already have an `np.histogram`

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(data)
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
```

The important part here is that your counts are simply the **weights**. If you do it like that, you don't need the bar function anymore

Answer (score 7):

### As of matplotlib 3.4.0

The new [**`plt.stairs`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) (or [**`ax.stairs`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stairs.html)) works directly with `np.histogram`:

- `np.histogram` returns counts and edges
- [**`plt.stairs`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) accepts counts and edges

For example, given unutbu's sample `x = 100 + 15 * np.random.randn(10000)`:

```py
counts, edges = np.histogram(x, bins=50)
plt.stairs(counts, edges, fill=True)
```

[image: plt.stairs with np.histogram]

Alternatively, unpack `np.histogram` directly into [**`plt.stairs`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html):

```py
plt.stairs(*np.histogram(x, bins=50), fill=True)
```

See the official matplotlib gallery for more example of [how to use stair plots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stairs_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stairs-demo-py).

Answer (score 6):

If you're willing to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
pandas.DataFrame({'x':hist[1][1:],'y':hist[0]}).plot(x='x',kind='bar')
```

Comment: If you are going to suggest using `pandas` you should probably include a link to their site and a more through example that explains what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful for someone.

Numpy's histogram function returns the edges of each bin, rather than the value of the bin. This makes sense for floating-point numbers, which can lie within an interval, but may not be the desired result when dealing with discrete values or integers (0, 1, 2, etc). In particular, the length of bins returned from np.histogram is not equal to the length of the counts / density.

To get around this, I used np.digitize to quantize the input, and count the fraction of counts for each bin. You could easily edit to get the integer number of counts.

```
def compute_PMF(data):
    import numpy as np
    from collections import Counter
    _, bins = np.histogram(data, bins='auto', range=(data.min(), data.max()), density=False)
    h = Counter(np.digitize(data,bins) - 1)
    weights = np.asarray(list(h.values())) 
    weights = weights / weights.sum()
    values = np.asarray(list(h.keys()))
    return weights, values
####
```

Refs:

[1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

[2]
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html