# Plotting histrogram from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram

I need to create histograms from the 2D arrays that I obtain from convolving an input array and a filter. The bins should as the range of the values in the array.

I tried following this example: [How does numpy.histogram() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141732/how-does-numpy-histogram-work?lq=1)
The code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.hist(result, bins = (np.min(result), np.max(result),1))
plt.show()
```

I always get this error message:

```
AttributeError: bins must increase monotonically.
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you look at `(np.min(result), np.max(result),1)`, do the values increase monotonically?

Comment: The min/max for my example is: '(0.0, 254.999999745)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are actually doing is specifying three bins where the first bin is `np.min(result)`, second bin is `np.max(result)` and third bin is `1`.  What you need to do is provide where you want the bins to be located in the histogram, and this **must** be in increasing order.  My guess is that you want to choose bins from `np.min(result)` to `np.max(result)`.  The 1 seems a bit odd, but I'm going to ignore it.  Also, you want to plot a 1D histogram of values, yet your **input is 2D**.  If you'd like to plot the distribution of your data over all unique values in 1D, you'll need to **unravel** your 2D array when using `np.histogram`.  Use [`np.ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) for that.

Now, I'd like to refer you to [`np.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace).  You can specify a minimum and maximum value and as many points as you want in between uniformly spaced.  So:

```
bins = np.linspace(start, stop)
```

The default number of points in between `start` and `stop` is 50, but you can override this:

```
bins = np.linspace(start, stop, num=100)
```

This means that we generate 100 points in between `start` and `stop`.

As such, try doing this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
num_bins = 100 # <-- Change here - Specify total number of bins for histogram
plt.hist(result.ravel(), bins=np.linspace(np.min(result), np.max(result), num=num_bins)) #<-- Change here.  Note the use of ravel.
plt.show()
```

Comment: I got this error message while implementing your example: 'UserWarning: 2D hist input should be nsamples x nvariables. this looks transposed (shape is 212 x 254)'.

Comment: I add that the min/max values are in float type.

Comment: @Litwos you didn't say that your input was 2D.  You failed to mention that.  Do you want to plot a **2D** histogram or 1D?

Comment: It's a 2D array, I mentioned in the first post.

Comment: So do you want a 2D histogram or 1D?

Comment: A simple 1D histogram with the values from the 2D array.

Comment: @Litwos - Then you need to **unravel** your 2D matrix so that it's a 1D matrix.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: It worked with the 'np.linspace' in the end. The error I posted in the previous comment doesn't seem to affect the results. Also, the 'np.ravel' method works as well. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Litwos - Sure! No problem :) Good luck!