# can any one explain about this code output

Tags: numpy, histogram

1.I have tried to understand this code but I couldn't.would you help me?

```
    a = np.arange(5)
    hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, density=True)
    hist
```

2.why is the output like this ?

```
    array([0.5, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5])
```

Comment: What don't you understand?  `arange` or `historgram`?  Have read the docs?  Looked at `a` and `bin_edges`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for the `bins` argument to `np.histogram` is 10. So the histogram counts which bins your array elements fall into. In this case `a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`. If we are creating a histogram with `10` bins then we break the interval 0-4 (inclusive) into 10 equal bins. This gives us (note that 11 end points gives us 10 bins):

```
np.linspace(0, 4, 11) = array([0. , 0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.6, 2. , 2.4, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 4. ])
```

We now just need to see which bins your elements in the array `a` fall into. We can count them as follows:

```
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Now this is still not exactly what the output is. The `density=True` argument states (from the docs): "If `True`, the result is the value of the
probability *density* function at the bin, normalized such that
the *integral* over the range is 1."

Each bin (of height `.5`) has a width of `.4` so `5 x .5 x .4 = 1` as is the requirement of this argument.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.arange(5)` generates a numpy array of 5 elements evenly spaced: array([0,1,2,3,4]).
`np.histogram(a, density=True)` returns the bin edges and the values of an histogram obtained from your array `a` using 10 bins (which is the default value).
bin_edges gives the edges of the bin, while histogram gives the number of occurrences for each bin. Given that you set `density=True` the occurrences are normalized (the integral over the range is 1.).

Look [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141732/how-does-numpy-histogram-work). Hint: When you call `np.histogram`, the default bin value is 10, so that's why your output has 10 elements.