# Connect the points to zero for missing points

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset like this,where I have a set of values for `xs` and I plot the corresponding line graph with the values of `ys`.

```
xs = np.array([1,2,5,6,9,10,11)
ys = pow(xs,2)
ys
plt.plot(xs, ys, linestyle='-', marker='o')


plt.show()
```

If you notice by default, plot connects the points and draws line. But, I want to draw the line at 0 for missing points. How do I do this ? Should I manipulate the data to fill missing values with zeros (numpy,maybe) or is there a way to plot this `matplotlib.plot` ?

To be precise I need to plot: `xs = np.array([1,2,0,0,5,6,0,0,9,10,11,0,0,0,0])`
    `ys = pow(xs,2)`
But, as of now, this is my `xs=np.array([1,2,5,6,9,10,11)`. How do i fill the missing elements in the range 1:15. I looked at `masked_array` which is different. Is there any other fill option in numpy ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to plot? I'd suggest just adding the zero, since it would work here, but depending on what you want to plot, different things may work better.

Comment: I'm trying to plot the frequency of occurrence of `xs` - which is `ys`, so that when there is a missing point it should be shown as zero occurrences.

Comment: Do you want to do a [histogram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328556/histogram-matplotlib)?

Comment: Yes you are right, but need to account for missing elements as well. I need a zero for missing points.

Comment: Not exactly. I described my dataset which is represented as the count of a particular entity. It is not like I need to plot a histogram. I need a scatter plot with values of `1:35` , with my y-value for missing values in range `1:35`, to be represented as zero.

Comment: Please provide an example of the input you have and a synthetic version of the output you want.

Comment: Edited the question to be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to plot points that aren't in your data set, it will be hard to do directly in matplotlib.  But, constructing the points is easy enough using [`put`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html#numpy.put):

```
xs = array([1,2,5,6,9,10,11])
ys = xs**2

x = arange(12)
y = zeros(12, dtype=int32)
put(y, xs, ys)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', clip_on=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome ! this is exactly the function I was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't dealing with an integer X axis, you can do this:

```
xs = array([1.0,2,5,6,9,10,11])
ys = xs**2

x = arange(0, 12, 0.5)
y = zeros(x.shape)
mask = r_[diff(searchsorted(xs, x)), 0]
y[mask == 1] = ys

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', clip_on=False)
```