# Matplotlib histogram from numpy histogram output

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have run [`numpy.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) on a bunch of subsets of a larger datasets. I want to separate the calculations from the graphical output, so I would prefer not to call [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) on the data itself.

In principle, both of these functions take the same inputs: the raw data itself, before binning. The `numpy` version just returns the `nbin+1` bin edges and `nbin` frequencies, whereas the `matplotlib` version goes on to make the plot itself.

So is there an easy way to generate the histograms from the [`numpy.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) output itself, without redoing the calculations (and having to save the inputs)?

To be clear, the [`numpy.histogram()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) output is a list of `nbin+1` bin edges of `nbin` bins; there is no `matplotlib` routine which takes those as input.

Comment: Have you tried [matplotlib bar](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Histogram Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328556/histogram-matplotlib)

Answer (score 26):

You can plot the output of `numpy.histogram` using `plt.bar`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

a = np.random.rayleigh(scale=3,size=100)
bins = np.arange(10)

frq, edges = np.histogram(a, bins)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(edges[:-1], frq, width=np.diff(edges), edgecolor="black", align="edge")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ya know, maybe you just caught me at a bad time, and I'm down with work-arounds, but it seems weird that plt.hist cannot take in the output from np.histogram.  What if you want to rescale the y-axis?  np.histogram's output makes that easy, then you could plot it easy.  What if you want histtype=u'step' ? now I have to figure that out in bar.  All of these work-arounds would just be solved if these two things that should work together did... Anyways, +1 lol

Comment: @kηives `plt.hist` is a wrapper for `np.histogram`. Since `np.histogram` does not take the output of a previous call to `np.histogram`, the same is true for `plt.hist`. The question is hence: Do you want to plot something you would obtain via `np.histogram`? If yes, use `plt.hist`, if no (e.g. because you need to manipulate the data), don't use `plt.hist`. This makes sense, because if you manipulate the data, it's not a histogram any more, so the `hist` function is not responible any more. To plot a step function, use `plt.step(...)`.

Comment: how would you write such a figure to disk?

Answer (score 6):

### New in matplotlib 3.4.0

It's no longer necessary to manually reconstruct a bar chart, as there's now a built-in method:

> Use the **new [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) method** for the common case where you know the values and edges of the steps, for instance when **plotting the output of [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html).**

Note that stairs are plotted as lines by default, so use `fill=True` for a solid histogram:

```py
a = np.random.RandomState(1).rayleigh(3, size=100)

counts, edges = np.histogram(a, bins=range(10))
plt.stairs(counts, edges, fill=True)
```

[image]

If you want a more conventional "bar" aesthetic, combine with [`plt.vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html):

```py
plt.stairs(counts, edges, fill=True)
plt.vlines(edges, 0, counts.max(), colors='w')
```

[image]

If you don't need the counts and edges, just unpack [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) directly into [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html):

```py
plt.stairs(*np.histogram(a), fill=True)
```

And as usual, there is an [`ax.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stairs.html) counterpart:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stairs(*np.histogram(a), fill=True)
```

Comment: Is it possible to have each of the bars with its own edgecolor? (I.e., which goes in between the bars, all the way down to the axis, as in the example in the other answer.)

Comment: @AndrewJaffe I added an option with [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html), but that will [only look good with white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmwOp.png). If you want any other edgecolor (e.g., black), `bar` is probably still the way to go.