# how to plot histogram data returned from numpy.hist?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I use numpy.histogram to create several histograms but I'm having issues in plotting them.
my code is basically:

```
hist_data, bin_edges = np.histogram(pw_dist, 10, (0, limit + 1), None, weights)
#perform some logic on histogram data
plt.hist(hist_data, bins=bin_edges)
```

hist_data is ([   0.,    0., 1176.,  576., 2628., 1680., 2952., 3312., 3444., 2904.])

and bin_edges are: ([ 0. ,  1.6,  3.2,  4.8,  6.4,  8. ,  9.6, 11.2, 12.8, 14.4, 16. ])

Which is good, however, when trying to plot it with the plt.hist, what I'm getting is:
[Histogram of above hist_data and bin_edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkd3o.png)
which doesn't really correspond with the values in the hist_data array.
So TLDR, how do I use matplotlib.pyplot hist function to plot the histogram correctly, given a histogram data/bins array?

Comment: As of matplotlib 3.4.0, you can use `plt.stairs(hist_data, bin_edges, fill=True)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/70846594/13138364

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [plt.bar](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html)?

```py
hist_data, bin_edges = np.histogram(pw_dist, 10, (0, limit + 1), None, weights)

# Plot the histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist_data, width=np.diff(bin_edges))
```

Note that we compute the width of the bins by taking the difference of neighboring elements in `bin_edges`.

The matplotlib hist function takes the raw data as input, so you could also try `plt.hist(pw_dist)` for a quick histogram plotting.

Comment: thank you, this help.
as for plt.hist, unfortunately I'm creating several histogram and than need to calculate the average counts per bean over all of them, so I can't really use plt,hist on the initial pw_dist data set, and I also can't aggregate them as it is some molecular dynamic simulation, so there is too much data to save through out the whole simulation.