# Is there a way to plot a histogram with given bin widths with Mathplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, bokeh

I have two lists given.
One, named "bin_edge", represents the lower and upper borders of 24 bins by 25 values. The second, named "counts", represents the according counts (=values) of each bin.

My aim is, if possible, to get a Matplotlib histogram that should look like somewhat that:

[image]

So, the first difficulty I face is that the first bin is a section located between the first two values of `bin_edge`, the second bin is a section between the second and the third element of `bin_edge` and so on...
Means that one value of `counts` is connected to the two bounds (lower and upper bound) of the `bin_edge` list.

And the second sticking point: I would like to draw logarithmic x and y axes.

The code I was trying:

```
bin_edge = [0.36, 0.46, 0.66, 1.00, 1.30, 1.70, 2.20, 3.00, 4.00, 
            5.20, 6.50, 8.00, 10.00, 12.00, 14.00, 16.00, 18.00, 
            20.00, 22.00, 25.00, 28.00, 31.00, 34.00, 37.00, 40.00]

counts = [159746491, 9316595, 855578, 166092, 151198, 41293, 51051, 
          26098, 38536, 1172, 2.872e-12, 24598, 3.27097e-12, 3.86874e-12, 
          4.46613e-12, 5.06328e-12, 5.6602754e-12, 6.2571442e-12, 4.6652e-12, 
          5.26229e-12, 5.8592429e-12, 0, 7.052837e-12, 0] 

plt.hist([counts], bins=bin_edge)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Size / µm')
plt.ylabel('counts')
plt.title('Histogram')
plt.show()
```

This leads to an empty plot.

Any other solutions beside Matplotlib including bokeh are welcome, of course as well :-)

Comment: I think you can use plt.step method

Comment: @Danil Kononyhin Do you have a suggestion how this could look like? I get an ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (25,) and (24,)

Comment: I just took first 24 elements of both arrays :) here is a similar question, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616617/matplotlib-plot-histogram-given-pre-computed-counts-and-bins

Comment: Also, here is GitHub issue related to this problem https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6669

Comment: @DanilKononyhin: well taking the first values only will draw a wrong bin center. The linked similar question is good -I didn`t find it. But as soon as I chose a logarithmic scale on both axes I also get an empty plot with that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have the heights for each bin, you should create a bar plot.

The x-values should be the bin edges, except for the last.  By default, the bars are centered; you need `align='edge'` to align them with the bin edges. The widths of the bars are the differences of the bin edges.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np

bin_edge = [0.36, 0.46, 0.66, 1.00, 1.30, 1.70, 2.20, 3.00, 4.00,
            5.20, 6.50, 8.00, 10.00, 12.00, 14.00, 16.00, 18.00,
            20.00, 22.00, 25.00, 28.00, 31.00, 34.00, 37.00, 40.00]
counts = [159746491, 9316595, 855578, 166092, 151198, 41293, 51051,
          26098, 38536, 1172, 2.872e-12, 24598, 3.27097e-12, 3.86874e-12,
          4.46613e-12, 5.06328e-12, 5.6602754e-12, 6.2571442e-12, 4.6652e-12,
          5.26229e-12, 5.8592429e-12, 0, 7.052837e-12, 0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.bar(x=bin_edge[:-1], height=counts, width=np.diff(bin_edge), align='edge', fc='MediumOrchid', ec='black')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('Size / µm')
ax.set_ylabel('counts')
ax.set_title('Histogram')
ax.margins(x=0.01)  # less margin left and right

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%g'))
# "length" is the length of the tick mark, it also changes the text offset
# "labelsize" is the fontsize of the tick label
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='minor', length=5, labelsize=8)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', length=10, labelsize=12)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with explicit bin edges]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot also for the helpful explanation of the alignment of the edges. This is a really big help for me in further python understanding :-) Nice Sunday.

Comment: would there anyhow the possibility to print also the minor ticks? I tried `from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, FixedFormatter
x_formatter = FixedFormatter(["0.1", "1", "10", "20"])
x_locator = FixedLocator([0.1, 1, 10, 20])
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(x_locator)` to test it but minor ticks are not shown

Comment: Is the updated answer what you're after?  See e.g. [show labels for minor ticks also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165435/matplotlib-show-labels-for-minor-ticks-also) for more ideas.

Comment: ok, that is working now. The minors shown minors seem not to be possible without the ax-object?

Comment: The  `ax` object is always created, whether you use it or not.  See e.g. https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/

Comment: ah, ok, that was a useful hint. Thanks a lot for the insight :-)