# How to plot a log-log histogram in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wondering how to have a log-log plot for visualizing the frequency of elements in a list, for example:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,3,3,4,1,2,5,2,10,4,5,3,3,3,2,1]
```

I plotted data using a histogram:

```
plt.hist(my_list, label='Frequency Distribution of matches')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
```

But it would be better to visualize it as log-log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) includes a `log` param, which behaves like [`plt.yscale('log')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) since it only scales the y-axis:

> `log`: If `True`, the **histogram axis** will be set to a log scale.

To also scale the x-axis, combine it with [`plt.xscale('log')`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xscale.html):

```
plt.hist(my_list, log=True)
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]

If you want equal-width bars, define `bins` as `10 ** edges`:

```
start, stop = np.log10(min(my_list)), np.log10(max(my_list))
bins = 10 ** np.linspace(start, stop, 10)

plt.hist(my_list, log=True, bins=bins)
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

To get a log-log line plot of the frequencies, use [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) (requires matplotlib 3.4+) with [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
plt.stairs(*np.histogram(my_list))
plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, tdy. Would it be possible to plot, instead of a histogram, a line plot using log=True?

Comment: @Math do you mean a log-log line plot of frequencies? if so, use [`plt.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) (requires matplotlib 3.4+) with [`np.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) (answer updated)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68201845/13138364 for more details on stair plots