# How to plot histogram for this data?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, histogram, special-characters, numeric

[I have a column of values that also contains '>75' like values.Need to make histogram. I've attached photo and written it down below. I tried with hist() function. but it shows 'no numeric data to plot'. also tried to convert the object type to numeric.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnXPC.jpg)
`pH tampon 65 45 76 46 65 >75 >75 >75`

```
enter code here
here is the ode I've tried.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df= pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Shahadat Shuchon\Documents\New 
folder\data_Luzrene 
gps\data_luzerne_analyse_gps_match_unmatch_revised.xlsx', 
sheet_name='QR_code_Match_unmatch')
df.head()

df.Season.unique()
df.columns
ssn = df[["Season", "Aluminium (Al)*ppm",'Bore (B)*ppm','CEC 
estiméemeq/100g','Calcium (Ca)*Kg/ha  ','Cuivre (Cu)*ppm','Fer (Fe)ppm', 
'ISP%', 'Indice en chaux', 'Magnésium (Mg)*Kg/ha  ','Manganèse 
(Mn)*ppm', 'Matière organique*%', 'Phosphore (P)*Kg/ha  ','Potassium 
(K)*Kg/ha  ', 'Saturation Ca%', 'Saturation K%','Saturation K+Mg+Ca%', 
'Saturation Mg%', 'Sodium (Na)Kg/ha  ','Zinc (Zn)*ppm', 'pH eau (1:1)*', 
'pH tampon*']]

spring=ssn.loc[(ssn['Season']== 'Spring')]
fall=ssn.loc[(ssn['Season']== 'Fall')]

fall['pH tampon*'].plot(kind='hist',color = "skyblue", rwidth=0.95)
plt.title('Fall')
plt.xlabel('pH tampon*')
plt.ylabel('No. of obsevation')
fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
plt.draw()
#fig1.savefig('season_pH tampon*.jpg', dpi= 500)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Histogram Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328556/histogram-matplotlib)

Comment: @DollarAkshay I have tried these solutions, but no. the columns contain some '>75' like values.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried.  It's likely that whatever library you're using to load the data can't understand the string `'> 75'` that's in your data -- you'll need to write some code (though nothing too complicated) to handle that.

Comment: Thanks -Rory Yorke. Now I have added my code.

Comment: Can you post the full code where you are reading the data from the csv file.

Comment: DollarAkshay - I have added the full code.