# Maximum commit message size

Tags: git

Is there any size limit to the Git commit message?
I searched trough the web but cannot find any relevant mention about this except [this one](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox-cvs/2010-March/030975.html).

However, that one does not answer my question.

Comment: why do you want to know the size? any specific background or reason?

Comment: If there's no limit, you can use Github's API as an append-only persistent log, with operations saved in commit messages as immutable log entries. Then you code the rest of the app as a set of data transformations: blog.confluent.io/2015/03/04/turning-the-database-inside-out-with-apache-samza/

Comment: If you're here looking for *best practices* around git commit message max length -- rather than the max length possible -- then this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2290016/12484

Answer (score 41, accepted):

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/strbuf.h defines the `len` field to be a `size_t`. So at the very least, the maximum length has an upper bound at the maximum value of `size_t` on your platform of choice.

Answer (score 64):

Empirically, I think the answer is no. This worked (that's a ~100MB commit message):

```
yes | head -c 100000000 | git commit -F - > /dev/null
```

Command parts explanation:

- `yes` repeats `"y\n"` forever
- `head -c 100000000` takes only the first 100,000,000 bytes (~100MB)
- `git commit -F -` commits with the passed-in commit message (this won’t work if you haven’t staged any changes to commit)
- `> /dev/null` hides the output from the command, which includes Git repeating back the very long commit message

Comment: Use `git commit --allow-empty -F -` to make a commit without any changes staged.

Answer (score 7):

Well, actually, there is a limit of ~5MB for JGit.

Of course, I've got to ask why anyone would do that?!  Especially since every subsequent clone would need to include that data.  I'd say that if you're going beyond a few KB then you really should be questioning your motives.