# bzr logs: Get just the commit messages

Tags: bazaar

Is there any way to get the logs from a bazaar repository (like with `bzr logs -v`), but with only the commit messages.

By default, for each commit, you have:
 revision number
 committer name
 branch nick
 timestamp
 message
 files modified.

I would like just the messages.

---

Some context, in case there is an other way to do what I want:
When I write release notes, I get the commit messages up to the last released version. Before rewriting the commit messages in user friendly english, I need to filter all the other elements. This is boring, and I'd prefer the computer to do it for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bzr log --short`, `bzr log --line`, `bzr log --gnu-changelog` or just `bzr log --gnu`.

See `bzr log --usage` and also `bzr help log-formats`.

One can add custom log formatter via plugin.

Comment: --line is dangerous, because I only get the first line of my commit.  --short is almost what I want, but for each commit I still get the "<revision number> <committer name> <date>". Any way to remove that?

Comment: @Guillaume you have to write a plugin to provide a custom log formatter.

Comment: @Guillaume try also `bzr log --gnu`

Comment: Or run the `bzr log --short` output through a text filter like perl or awk.

Comment: @bialix It does not produced desired effect (still get date and commiter details).

Comment: @dOxxx I thought about it, but what criteria do I use to filter the lines I don't want? I could work on the --xml output, but seems overkill for my need.

Comment: I realize this won't help in your current situation, but I find using a git-style commit message policy helps -- first line is a summary of changes, blank line, then more details if necessary. Also described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290016/git-commit-messages-50-72-formatting

Comment: As for solving your current problem, grep is your friend: `bzr log --short | grep -Ev '^ *[0-9]+ [[:alpha:] ]+'`