# Standard to follow when writing git commit messages

Tags: git, git-commit, commit-message

I find myself managing very many files (over 60 but below 70) and my commit messages so far follow this pattern:
when I have added something like on `layout.css`, my commit message is *"added something on layout.css file"*, and when I remove something, my commit message is *"removed something from layout.css file"*.

Some files down the line, I look at my commits feed and *added...* and  *removed...* messages dominate. Sometimes I don't remember what I removed or what I added in `layout.css` since I make so many changes at a go and so I struggle to come up with an appropriate commit message.

Is there a standard I should follow to help me come up with my commit messages?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290016/git-commit-messages-50-72-formatting

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the one linked. This question asks about commit message content, whereas the linked question asks about a specific formatting practice.

Comment: See also: http://www.commitlogsfromlastnight.com/ and https://whatthecommit.com/ ... and of course https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/375fjr/whats_the_most_humorous_commit_message_youve_ever/ ;-)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

When you just describe what you've done (in technical yet fuzzy terms like "added a function"), you're not adding much to what Git already stores in the commit. Imagine yourself reading the commit message some time later; what kind of summary would help you most remembering / communicating to other developers the essence of that change?! The exact contents depend on your project and processes, but I find that a good guideline.

Therefore, first and foremost add context (the *why*, not the *how*) with your commit message (e.g. "frobnize the message to enable persistence") instead of "added frob() function"). It's more effort (you have to reflect and *think*), but it is worth so much more.

If you want to explore more about this topic, there's a wealth of information, for example [this blog article by Peter Hutterer](http://who-t.blogspot.de/2009/12/on-commit-messages.html) or [this funny slide](http://www.slideshare.net/TarinGamberini/commit-messages-goodpractices).

Comment: +1 for emphasizing the ***why*** instead of the *how*.

Comment: @Bernard: That's just a dummy nonsense verb, as a placeholder. Origin in "frob" and "frobnicate" from the [Jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/F/frob.html).

Comment: + for [this funny slide](http://www.slideshare.net/TarinGamberini/commit-messages-goodpractices)

Answer (score 44):

The 50/72 model seems to be a good practice. i.e. ... the first line should be maximum 50 chars long and should server as a header. Followed by a space, the second set of line(s) should be wrapped at 72 chars and should serve as a summary. Here is a SO question : [Git Commit Messages : 50/72 Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290016/git-commit-messages-50-72-formatting), that discusses the same.

Here are some exhaustive notes on the subject:

1. [GIT Commit Good Practice](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/GitCommitMessages)
2. [A Note About Git Commit Messages](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html)
3. [Proper Git Commit Messages and an Elegant Git History](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/03/23/proper-git-commit-messages-and-an-elegant-git-history)

Answer (score 12):

Git already knows which files you modified in a commit, it's useless to  specify it in the comment. Just say for example "fixed padding bug" or "added menu in sidebar". Make it clear, that's it.

Comment: The underlying reason is also great to have: "Padding made Edge wrap the menu bar" or "Menubar fits better in sidebar than in header bar (UX rule 42)"

Comment: Actually, in Git, you should use a message the makes it clear what the patch _will do_ when applied to a repository - not was _was_ done (more common in other vcs). Therefore `Fix padding bug` and `Add menu in sidebar` would be more conventional. See [Use the imperative mood in the subject line](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#imperative) (and also see [Capitalize the subject line](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#capitalize))