# How to enable the horizontal scroll bar in git gui commit message edit control

Tags: git, user-interface, tk-toolkit, git-gui

I'm using latest `msysgit` and I can run the `git gui` to write the commit message. But I see the the message edit control don't have the horizontal scroll bar. See the image shot below(I just labeled 1).
[image: screen shot of git gui window]
Another issue I see is that how can I extend this window to the right bored of the window(I just labeled 2). Thanks.
I notice this is a TK application, and I just check that my git gui version is 0.19, which is the latest release version. See: http://repo.or.cz/w/git-gui.git

Comment: You don't. Make your first line messages shorter and use line breaks for longer text. It's good practice.

Comment: Thanks, after some search, I found that git commit message show follow some simple rules, such as [Git Commit Messages : 50/72 Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290016/git-commit-messages-50-72-formatting), so the git gui just follow this rule and disable the horizontal scroll bar deliberately.

Comment: I was taught in college to never write more horizontally then the screen allows because programmers are lazy and don't want to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixed width and lack of horizontal scroll bar in this control is a design decision made to encourage well formatted comments in accordance with the git and Linux projects commit style recommendations