# What does this master.. thing do, and why does it not work in Windows CMD?

Tags: git, cmd

I don't use Linux or bash. I have to run this command in Windows on CMD:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty=format:'- %s -- %cn' --full-history master..`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` > ReleaseNotes.txt
```

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty=format:"- %s -- %cn" --full-history master..`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` > ReleaseNotes.txt
```

But this is giving me an error about an ambiguous argument 'master..`git'.

This command works in bash but I don't use bash. I use Windows CMD.

Comment: The command includes a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution); you'll have to replace it with the `CMD` equivalent.

Comment: Note that you may wish to switch to using bash or perhaps PowerShell. Both are far more capable than the klunky old CMD.EXE. PowerShell seems to have a lot of annoyances to me and I personally would avoid it, but then again I also avoid Windows to all possible extents. 

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the two dots, but rather the backquote command-substitution (and, as you found, the kind of quote mark: `CMD.EXE` demands double quotes rather than single quotes, here; see [What does single-quoting do in Windows batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24173825/1256452)).

The backquoted part (`` `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` ``) is a bit silly since it can be replaced by just using `HEAD` directly:

```
git log --no-merges --pretty=format:"- %s -- %cn" --full-history master..HEAD > ReleaseNotes.txt
```

as the backquoted bit simply resolves `HEAD` to a raw hash ID, then abbreviates it to a short hash ID, but `git log` can take the full hash ID *or* the name `HEAD` directly.

There are a few more things we can do here.  Let's break this up the edited command into pieces and describe each one:

> ```
> git log 
> --no-merges
> --pretty=format:"- %s -- %cn"
> --full-history
> master..HEAD
> > ReleaseNotes.txt
> ```

- The `git log` command walks some set of commits in the repository, and displays some sub-set of the walked commits.  "Walking", in this case, means visiting nodes in a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).
- The `--no-merges` part tells `git log` that it should not *display* any merge commits.  It will still use them for the graph-walk; it will just omit them from its output.  A merge commit is any commit with two or more parent commits.
- The `--pretty=format:...` section tells `git log` *how* to display a commit, when it goes to display it.  The `format` part tells it that instead of a pre-coooked format like `full`, `fuller`, `oneline`, and the like, we're going to give `git log` a string that may contain *individual formatting directives* as well as literal characters to display.  Since some of the characters will include blanks, we need the command-line-interpreter not to break up arguments *at* the blanks, hence the quotes.

  The actual format here is hyphen, space, `%s`, space, double hyphen, space, and `%cn`.  Each of the non-percent-prefixed sequences is output literally; `%s` outputs the *subject line* of the commit log message; and `%cn` outputs the *committer name:*

  - The commit log message is whatever the author / committer provided to Git, and its "subject line" is very roughly the first line of the message.  See more at [Git Commit Messages: 50/72 Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2290016/1256452).
  - The *committer name* is the `user.name` setting from whoever made the *commit*.  This may be different from the *author name* (`%an`), though in most cases author and committer are the same person.  The split occurs when the committer is applying an emailed commit, or using `git cherry-pick` on a commit written by someone else, or in other similar cases.  (Technically, anyone can override the committer name and/or author name at any point, just as one can set `user.name` to anything one wishes, so these are more cultural distinctions than technical ones.)

  The `git log` command generally ensures that the format has a newline added as needed, though there's `tformat` to make extra doubly sure, and that's what one should generally use here (in case of tools that can't handle a final partial output line).  In Git versions since 1.6.3 (all extant Git versions that I know of), instead of `--pretty=tformat:` we can just write `--format=`, which is what I would recommend here.
- The `--full-history` option disables "History Simplification".  History simplification is a process where `git log` omits parts of the graph *from* the graph walk.  But history simplification is only turned *on* if we add options that we don't use here, so there's no need to turn it *off* either.  This option can therefore be omitted entirely.
- `master..HEAD` is a *range* syntax.  It's literally short for `HEAD ^master`.  The details are in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  `HEAD` here is a *positive* reference, i.e., it tells `git log` which commit(s) should be *included* in the revision walk, and `^master` here is a *negative* reference, i.e., it tells `git log` which commit(s) should be *excluded* in the revision walk.  The actual walking is a bit complicated and I'll omit all the details, but note that when using the `A..B` syntax (which means `^A B` aka `B ^A`), omitting one name from either side of the two dots is equivalent to writing `HEAD`.  So instead of `master..HEAD` we can just write `master..`.  Do make sure to use exactly *two* dots here, as *three* dots means something else entirely (again, see the documentation).
- Last, `> ReleaseNotes.txt` is an output redirection, which works the same in `CMD.EXE` as it does in sh, bash, and other Unix-style shells.

Omitting defaults, then, our final short version of the command is:

```
git log --no-merges --format="- %s -- %cn" master.. > ReleaseNotes.txt
```